# Вопрос по getElementById

Tags: javascript

Доброе время суток, подскажите почему не переносит в value getElementById если в input стоит  type="text" ???  когда type="hidden" все норм.

```
     function(data){
        if (data){
        document.getElementById('col').value =  data.quantity
        document.getElementById('nds').value =  data.tax
    }
}

<input id="col" size="5" placeholder="Кол-во"  type="text" value="" />
<input id="nds" size="5"  placeholder="НДС ( % )" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

возможно в data.quantity пусто. как видите http://jsfiddle.net/tskxd/ все там заносится